# ¿Cómo agregar datos de un array en JS a un Chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Debe ser alguna tontería pero no entiendo porqué no funciona, quiero agregar los datos que contiene un array en el label del Chart.

Contenido del array:

```
Array(8) [ "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-14", "2020-01-15" ]
```

He intentado lo siguiente sin éxito:

```
data: {
            labels: [ for(var a=0; a<=fechas_mov.lenght; a++){ fechas_mov[a]+', '; } ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bienvenido.

El problema está en que chartjs **ya está esperando un array**. Por tanto, no hace falta que especifiques ni hagas ninguna operación para que chartjs cargue la información en la sección "labels". Tu tan solo tienes que poner la variable que sea la array y punto.

En tu caso:

```
var titulos = ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-14", "2020-01-15"];

var grafico = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: {
        labels: titulos
    }    
});
```

El resto de información ya lo llenarás tu según tengas en tu proyecto.

Comment: Claro!! No me había dado cuenta, gracias!

Comment: Gracias a ti. Si te ha funcionado, recuerda votar positivo a la respuesta, de este modo será útil para el resto de usuarios que tengan la misma duda ;)